# Can't access global inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox, network-profile

I can't access my global inbox.  When I try to [go there](https://stackexchange.com/users/935589/gerrit?tab=inbox), I get *Oops! Something Bad Happened!*.

I am currently part of one private beta, that may be related.  I have also noticed that sometimes (but not always), the drop-down inbox link at the top shows old items only.  That may or may not be related.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: Not for gerrit, @sha - it's a transient error. Happening for others though.

Comment: @Sho is there a fix at the moment? How long is this short time?

Comment: @Shog9 so should we close other reports as dupe of this one, or let each stay open until fixed?